# Firebase ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

sorry I don't speak very well English.

My problem is that in the next fragment of code,
in valueEventListener, not enter, I don't know why, so, I can't getValue of "cantidad" of my realtime database.

The databaseReference get correctly, but when get the line     eventValueEventListener = new Value..., not enter in onDataChange() method.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

```
btnGoToEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(auth != null && btnGoToEvent.getText().equals("¡ME APUNTO!")) {
                btnGoToEvent.setText("Al final no voy a ir");
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Eventos").child(String.valueOf(position));
                valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        cantidad = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("cantidad").getValue().toString());
                        cantidad++;
                        databaseReference.setValue(cantidad);
                        databaseReference.push().setValue(new User(auth.getEmail()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };

            }else if(auth != null && btnGoToEvent.getText().equals("Al final no voy a ir")){
                btnGoToEvent.setText("¡ME APUNTO!");

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Necesita estar registrado para apuntarse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're doing there is creating a new ValueEventListener.  That won't get any callback until you add it to a Reference to listen to.

Maybe you meant to also write this line to set that up?

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Ohh yes of course, thank you very much, I don't remember this.